# Jenkins - override previous build

Tags: git, jenkins, sinatra

I have a project that builds a ruby server (Sinatra).
Jenkins clones the git source and build the server.
i want that every time i push to git Jenkins will create a new build, but the previous build is still running and preventing the new build from create.

the error is:
" pending—Build #BUILD_NUMBER is already in progress (ETA:N/A)) "

help?

Answer (score 0):

In the settings screen of the build job there is a check box with the name of "Execute concurrent builds if necessary" in the top section of the page. It won't stop a build from running, but as long as enough build agents/slots exist, it will build concurrently.